# Fail to setup Keycloak with Spring Boot Security UnsatisfiedDependencyException with KeycloakAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, keycloak

have a little trouble with keycloack and spring security.

Here the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.world</groupId>
    <artifactId>having-fun</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>having-fun</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>4.5.0.Final</keycloak.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.70</kotlin.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>development</profile>
                        <profile>docker</profile>
                    </profiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and here is the Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project activation-service-backend: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setKeycloakConfigResolvers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'keycloakConfigResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'KeycloakConfigResolver': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference? -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea what is wrong .. i belive its from the pom.xml but i don't know why?
Thx in advance

---

And thanks to this ***** rules i have to provide much more details, even if there existing not more of them . So i create some text without any content. If you are read up to this point stop it please because there will be only letters but no information ... now lets try if i wrote enought

Comment: Keycloak 4.5.0 wasn't built against 2.1.0 of boot (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/4.5.0.Final/adapters/oidc/spring-boot2/pom.xml#L34) so if you could check with an older version of boot that might help to narrow the problem down. You could also try jetty or undertow to see whether that error is specific to the default embedded tomcat

Comment: I have spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE and Keycloak 4.5 integration working but I am not using any keycloak jars. please refer to documentation here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter and https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter

Comment: Also, if you are building a resource server I would suggest to use Spring 5.1 security features to setup resource server.

Comment: i read the documents already @ChirdeepTomar but i cannot see doing anything wrong ... even add this filter registration beans they mentioned .. is it possible just using simple OAuth with Keycloak and Spring Boot Security?

Comment: @RyanDawson i tried also with spring boot 2.0.3 but it does not work too ...

Comment: @IEE1394 Yes, it is thats what I am suggesting. There should be no dependency on Keycloak jars if you consider microservices architecture as Keycloak is just an OIDC provider. Is your Spring Boot a web app or a Rest API?

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar its a REST API do you have an example of a OIDC spring boot app with keycloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following dependencies in build.gradle or pom.xml

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose",
            "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server"
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: sociter
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}
```

And setup the websecurity as here:

https://github.com/jzheaux/messaging-app/blob/master/resource-server/src/main/java/sample/config/ResourceServerConfig.java

More details: https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/21/spring-security-5-1-0-rc1-released#oauth2-resource-server

Comment: thank you .. but if i also want to provider the possibility to login from the REST API than i must behave like a client? not just a resource server?

Comment: Read about the Access_Type on client in Keycloak. A REST API is a backend service that is protected by Bearer Token so you can't login on the API, you need to pass in a Bearer Token in the Authorization header to access the API. Docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#oidc-clients

Comment: sorry for asking maybe a little stupid .. what i want is a microservice with a REST API which is secured by spring security using OAuth2 and e.g. Keycloak for authentication. If no valid JWT is provieded the microservice should redirect to keycloak and hopefully come back with a valid JWT. Is there anything wrong about that? currently i'm a little bit lost in confusion :-)

Comment: Don't worry :) It is not microservice's responsibility to do the redirect, microservice is just a backend API that simply expects a valid token from some OIDC provider like Keycloak, Okta, Auth0 or AzureAD. You will pass in a JWT into the Spring Boot microservice, your front end whether its a SPA, Mobile App or a Desktop app will authenticate with Keycloak to get that JWT Token. Whether its a redirect or a call from SPA to token endpoint, it depends on the type of client you are building.

Comment: okay .. but currently i have no frontend ... so how do you suggest to work around? get the jwt in browser or with postman?

Comment: Postman: you should have a call this curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 90787d63-46e4-4da0-a464-c7094a5b27e7' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=postman-client&password=112&scope=openid%20email%20profile&username=test-admin'

Comment: one more question .. what if i have a microservice which needs both .. beeing a resource server and also a client to another resource server somewhere outside with another identity provider?

Comment: Depends which authorisation server that resource server is protected by, if its the same instance of keycloak, then you can just forward the jwt token in the authorization header in the rest template or httpclient.

Comment: No its not the same ...currently i have to deal with three different services secured by three different authorisation server ...

Comment: Your token generated from keycloak won't work on those authorisation servers. You might need to look at openid connect provider like Github and see there is one in the list for your other authorisation server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182926/discussion-between-iee1394-and-chirdeep-tomar).