# BeanCreationException spring boot and keycloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

While trying to follow the article https://sandor-nemeth.github.io/java/spring/2017/06/15/spring-boot-with-keycloak.html

I set up my keycloak oauth in spring boot application exactly the same apart form the fact that I am using maven pom.xml instead of gradle.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The Java part is the same as in the article:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfigurer extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {

    final SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    mapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);

    final KeycloakAuthenticationProvider provider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(mapper);

    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}

@Bean
public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    super.configure(http);

    http.authorizeRequests();
}
```

While trying to start the spring boot application

```
java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar "${HOME}/app.war" "$@"
```

I am getting BeanInCreationException:

> rg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setKeycloakSpringBootProperties' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakSecurityConfigurer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'keycloakConfigResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakConfigResolver': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext","thread":"main","level":"WARN"}
>   {"time":"2020-03-10T12:53:22.667+00:00","msg":"Application run failed","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread":"main","level":"ERROR","stack_trace":"org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setKeycloakSpringBootProperties' parameter 1

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087259/fail-to-setup-keycloak-with-spring-boot-security-unsatisfieddependencyexception) will help